# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable selinium

Tags: selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>           driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
>       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
driver = webdriver.chrome(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

In webdriver.Chrome(), first letter of Chrome should be in Caps.